# Display an image based on pixels from background

Tags: html, css

what i need is that i insert image 1 on the website. After i did that, i want to display image 2 on position relative, top 5 etc INSIDE the image 1. So, if i move the image 1 the image 2 will still be on same position over the image 1.

I have try to put image 2 with relative pos over image 1. But when i move image 1 the image 2 is still at the old position.

CSS

```
.image1 {
    background-color:#F2630A;
    margin:10px;
    padding:10px;
    height:250px;
    width:250px;
}
.image2 img {
    // Here I'm lost. Tried with position relative but it's not a good way.   
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="image1">
   <div class="image2">
       <img src="items/test.gif">
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: have you tried setting `position:relative` on `.image2` instead of `.image2 img`?

Comment: @anurupr, yes i have. Same output

Comment: `.image2` shuld be positioned absolutely to `.image1` which should have `position:relative`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine `absolute` and `relative` positioning for that. If I understand your question properly, the following should achieve what you need:

```
.image1 {
    position: relative;
    background-color:#F2630A;
    margin:10px;
    padding:10px;
    height:250px;
    width:250px;
}

    .image1 .image2 {
        position: absolute;
        top: 5px;
        left: 5px;
        width: 240px;
        height: 240px;
    }
        .image1 .image2 img {
            max-width: 100%;
        }
```

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/NY6FF/)

Comment: Thanks, exactly what i searching for!

Answer (score 0):

Make parent Absolute and child Relative

Like image1 should be absolute and image 2 should be relative